# How to modify (or just read) request stream before it is piped?

Tags: node.js, express

I have following code:

```
app.post('/someurl',function(req,res,next){
    var request = require('request').post('/otherurl');
    var response = '';
    request.on('data',function(chunk){
        response += chunk;
    });
    var pipe = req.pipe(parser).pipe(request);

    request.on('end',function(){
        var res2 = pipe.response;
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        res.json(obj);
    });
});
```

So it just pipes POST request to other url. What I need is to know body of the piped request. So I added this (this code should do nothing):

```
    var Transform = require('stream').Transform;
    var parser = new Transform();
    parser._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {
        this.push(data);
        done();
    };
```

and changed `req.pipe(request)` to `req.pipe(parser).pipe(request)`. The problem is that this does not work - req is not piped to req, but only to parser...

---

The problem was with Authorization - actually req.pipe(parser).pipe(request) worked but it returned 401 Authorization error. The problem is how I can pass Authorization header to the piped request?

Comment: Have you tried adding `data` event listeners to the incoming stream, alongside the pipe?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean... When I dont pipe req twice it works correct and returns correct json response. When I pipe twice (`req.pipe(transform).pipe(request)`) then request handler `on('data',...)` is never called but `on('end',...)` is called but response is empty string (because on.data was never called)...